# Extending a protocol defined in external lib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, protocols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning while adding and using a new method in external library protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771957/warning-while-adding-and-using-a-new-method-in-external-library-protocol)

Is there any way to add another method in a protocol which is part of some other library?

I am using a external library and one of my view controller is registering as delegate for a class in that framework. Now, at one place I want to execute some code on this delegate class. I am writing a method for that and calling it on my delegate.

Now, all works fine but I am getting a warning that this newly added method is not part of the protocol.

I want to get rid of this warning.

P.S. This protocol has been defined in the external lib.