# Warning while adding and using a new method in external library protocol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, delegates

I am using a external library and one of my view controller is registering as delegate for a class in that framework. Now, at one place I want to execute some code on this delegate class. I am writing a method for that and calling it on my delegate.

Now, all works fine but I am getting a warning that this newly added method is not part of the protocol.

**This is my Class:**

```
@protocol MyExtendedDelegate <LibraryDelegate>

@optional

- (void)actionTaken;

@end

@interface MyController : UITableController <MyExtendedDelegate> {  

}

@end
```

**And inside my controller I am registering self as delegate for library controller**

```
LibraryController *libController = [[LibraryController alloc] init];
    libController.delegate = self;
```

**Finally, This is the code in a separate class where I am calling this method:**

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if ([self.libraryController.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(actionTaken)]) {
        [self.libraryController.delegate actionTaken];
    }
```

**Here is the warning I am getting:**

***-- actionTaken not found in protocol

-- NSObject may not respond to actionTaken***

I want to get rid of this warning. Any idea.

Answer (score 1):

The property `libraryController.delegate` is defined in the external library to conform to `LibraryDelegate`. Try to downcast to `MyExtendedDelegate` before you call the method from your extended protocol.

```
if ([self.libraryController.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyExtendedDelegate)])
{
    id<MyExtendedDelegate> extendedDelegate = (id<MyExtendedDelegate>)self.libraryController.delegate;
    if ([extendedDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(actionTaken)])
    {
        [extendedDelegate actionTaken];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a new protocol that extends the old one, and conform to that, something like:

```
@protocol MyNewProtocol <OtherProtocol>
   - (void) myCoolMethod;
@end
```

Comment: I did so but the warning is still coming.

Comment: And you are declaring support for MyNewProtocol instead of OtherProtocol, and also importing the header file that declares OtherProtocol?

Answer (score -1):

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
  if ([self.libraryController.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(actionTaken)]) {
      [self.libraryController.delegate performSelector:@selector(actionTaken)];
  }

Using performSelector instead of directly calling a method will remove warning for sure.